# Android ActionBar causing build-error (No resource found)

Tags: android, maven, build, android-actionbar, android-maven-plugin

Tried a sample-project with [johannilssons android-actionbar plugin](https://github.com/johannilsson/android-actionbar) and it worked fine. Tried it on another project and got this error. Thoughts on how to proceed in locating the source of the error?

```
   [INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building HSR Android Frontend 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-android-plugin:2.8.4:generate-sources (default-generate-sources) @ frontend-module ---
[INFO] ANDROID-904-002: Found aidl files: Count = 0
[INFO] ANDROID-904-002: Found aidl files: Count = 0
[INFO] Copying local resource files to combined resource directory.
[INFO] C:\Google\android-sdk-windows/platform-tools/aapt.exe [package, -m, -J, C:\Users\Love\workspace\HSR\HSR\frontend-module\target\generated-sources\r, -M, C:\Users\Love\workspace\HSR\HSR\frontend-module\AndroidManifest.xml, -S, C:\Users\Love\workspace\HSR\HSR\frontend-module\target\generated-sources\combined-resources\res, -I, C:\Google\android-sdk-windows\platforms\android-7\android.jar]
[INFO] C:\Users\Love\workspace\HSR\HSR\frontend-module\target\generated-sources\combined-resources\res\layout\main.xml:18: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'style' with value '@style/ActionBar').
[ERROR] Error when generating sources.
org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: 
    at com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.phase01generatesources.GenerateSourcesMojo.generateR(GenerateSourcesMojo.java:313)
    at com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.phase01generatesources.GenerateSourcesMojo.execute(GenerateSourcesMojo.java:111)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:319)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:534)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.ExecutionException: ANDROID-040-001: Could not execute: Command = cmd.exe /X /C "C:\Google\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\aapt.exe package -m -J C:\Users\Love\workspace\HSR\HSR\frontend-module\target\generated-sources\r -M C:\Users\Love\workspace\HSR\HSR\frontend-module\AndroidManifest.xml -S C:\Users\Love\workspace\HSR\HSR\frontend-module\target\generated-sources\combined-resources\res -I C:\Google\android-sdk-windows\platforms\android-7\android.jar", Result = 1
    at com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.CommandExecutor$Factory$1.executeCommand(CommandExecutor.java:186)
    at com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.phase01generatesources.GenerateSourcesMojo.generateR(GenerateSourcesMojo.java:311)
    ... 22 more
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `res/values/styles.xml` has the ActionBar style in it.

Comment: Example application don't has such a definition... [github](https://github.com/johannilsson/android-actionbar/blob/master/actionbarexample/res/values/styles.xml)